# Get a JSON as POST parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post

I have a ruby application and I need to receive a JSON from a client. Receiving a JSON is just like receiving a string? I just have to do something like:

```
information = params[:json_data]
data_parsed = JSON.parse(information)
```

That's all or I have to do something different when getting a JSON? The sender has to send me that like string?

Thanks!

Comment: but is there any other way of doing these? Or just getting it with params?

Comment: You're doing it right already. The payload of the POST request will always be inside your params Hash as a String (Or a nested Hash, but the values will always be Strings). It makes no difference what the actual datatype or data structure is.

The same way you can't send 1 as an Integer, you can't send {json: true} as some kind of JSON object or Hash.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [official document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters) says,

> If the "Content-Type" header of your request is set to
> "application/json", Rails will automatically load your parameters into
> the params hash, which you can access as you would normally.
>
> So for example, if you are sending this JSON content:
>
> ```
> { "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }
> ```
>
> Your controller will receive `params[:company]` as `{ "name" => "acme", "address" => "123 Carrot Street" }`.
>
> Also, if you've turned on `config.wrap_parameters` in your initializer or called `wrap_parameters` in your controller, you can safely omit the root element in the JSON parameter. In this case, the parameters will be cloned and wrapped with a key chosen based on your controller's name. So the above JSON POST can be written as:
>
> ```
> { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" }
> ```
>
> And, assuming that you're sending the data to CompaniesController, it would then be wrapped within the `:company` key like this:
>
> ```
> { name: "acme", address: "123 Carrot Street", company: { name: "acme", address: "123 Carrot Street" } }
> ```

So, if you send/POST `{ "hello": "world"}` to `apples/`, then
`params['apple']` will be the object for the Json payload.

```
class ApplesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # params['apple'] is the object represents Json payload
  end
end
```

Comment: Do note that `deep_munge` will sometimes mess with params, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13766

Answer (score 27):

What you are describing is OK, but it implies that there is a param named `json_data`. If you instead mean that the entire `POST` body is nothing but the `JSON`, then you want to look at [`request.raw_post`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/raw_post). You'd end up with something like this:

```
information = request.raw_post
data_parsed = JSON.parse(information)
```